# Listview custom Row - not high enough

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which contains custom rows. When I show the listview with it's custom rows, all the rows only have a height of about 2px. I tried it on an Android 4.0 device, and on an emulator which has Android 2.x. I added a screenshot of the problem.
Prepare, here comes quite a lot of code:

This is my code for my custom row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="105px"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8px"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="#322a37"
        android:textSize="11pt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code in my activity:

```
public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private ArrayList<User> m_items;
    private ObjectAdapter m_adapter;
    private EditText textSearch;
    private ListView listView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        textSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        m_items = new ArrayList<User>();

        //(fill m_items, goes well)

        this.m_adapter = new ObjectAdapter(this, R.layout.row_text, m_items);
        listView.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);

    }

    private class ObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

        private ArrayList<User> items;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public ObjectAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<User> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_text, null);
            }
            User u = items.get(position);
            if (u != null) {
                TextView top = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);

                if (top != null) {
                    top.setText(u.getName());
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The screenshot of the result:]

Anyone any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

does not strike me as being particularly clever.

Comment: Lol.. How can I be so stupid. Thanks man, didn't see this typo after searching for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your custom row xml and correct the hight of the TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="105px"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="15dp" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/toptext"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="8px"
android:gravity="top"
android:text="name"
android:textColor="#322a37"
android:textSize="11pt" />
```